# change local coordinates of an object(swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, drawrect

I draw a custom UIbutton. Now I want, that the 0,0-point is in the middle of the object. Not on top-left-corner. So If I set the position of this button in a view to the middle point of the view, the button is really in the middle and I dont have to add the half of the width and the half of the height.

Example:

If I set the position of the object to the middle of a view it should look this:
[image: right position]
and not like this:
[image: false position]

Comment: You can use "center" property to set it like wise.
Ex : btn.center = view.center

Comment: This is tagged with "drawrect". Do you want to translate the coordinate system inside the `drawRect:` method to put 0,0 in the center of the view or is simply changing the position of the view (setting its `center`, for example) all you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're modifying the origin of the frame, each view has a property `center` which does exactly what you want.